# Is there an "axis equal" in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, svg, data-visualization

I am using D3 and Python to create some plots. With Python I am able to do axis equal, as shown in image 1:

[image: With Axis Equal in Python]

I want to achieve the same in an SVG using D3. Please refer to the image 2, without axis equal:

[image: Without Axis Equal in Javascript d3]

The axes scale which I am using are as follows:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([minX, maxX]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([minY, maxY]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);
```

Could anyone tell me how can I achieve the axis equal with D3?

Comment: For having an *"axis equal"* equivalent something has to change: either the domain or the range. Therefore, you need to tell us which one (domain or range) do you want to change.

Comment: @Gerardo Thank you so much for replying. I cannot change the domain for sure. How to do the axis equal if range is changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: no, there is no *"axis equal"* in D3. D3 is quite low level, it's just a collection of methods, so you have to do almost everything *by hand*...

The good news is that all you need for solving your problem is some math to calculate the new ranges.

As an introduction, since this is a [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) tagged question, *"axis equal"* is a term used in some programs like [Matlab](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html), which...

> Use the same length for the data units along each axis.

It can be better explained visually. Have a look at this image, with different domains and ranges ([source](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html)):

[image]

After this brief introduction, let's go back to your problem. Suppose this simple code, generating two axes:

```js
const minX = 0,
  minY = 0,
  maxX = 120,
  maxY = 50,
  width = 500,
  height = 300,
  paddings = [10, 10, 20, 30];

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([paddings[3], width - paddings[1]])
  .domain([minX, maxX]);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height - paddings[2], paddings[0]])
  .domain([minY, maxY]);

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - paddings[2]})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeInner(-height + paddings[2] + paddings[0]));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${paddings[3]},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickValues(xScale.ticks()).tickSizeInner(-width + paddings[3] + paddings[1]));
```

```css
svg {
  border: 2px solid tan;
}

line {
  stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
  stroke: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As we can clearly see, the units are not equally spaced. We can do two things for creating axes with equally spaced units:
 1. Change the domains;
 2. Change the ranges.

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262026/is-there-an-axis-equal-in-d3?noredirect=1#comment104737859_59262026), changing the domains is not an option. So, let's change the ranges instead.

All we need is calculating the number of units per user space, and using the biggest among them (x or y) to change the range of the opposite scale.

For instance, given the scales of the snippet above:

```
const xStep = Math.abs((xScale.domain()[1] - xScale.domain()[0]) / (xScale.range()[1] - xScale.range()[0]));

const yStep = Math.abs((yScale.domain()[1] - yScale.domain()[0]) / (yScale.range()[1] - yScale.range()[0]));
```

`xStep` is bigger than `yStep`, showing us that the x axis has more units per pixels. Therefore, we'll change the y axis range:

```
yScale.range([yScale.range()[0], yScale.range()[0] - (yScale.domain()[1] - yScale.domain()[0]) / xStep]);
```

And here is the demo:

```js
const minX = 0,
  minY = 0,
  maxX = 120,
  maxY = 50,
  width = 500,
  height = 300,
  paddings = [10, 10, 20, 30];

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([paddings[3], width - paddings[1]])
  .domain([minX, maxX]);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height - paddings[2], paddings[0]])
  .domain([minY, maxY]);

const xStep = Math.abs((xScale.domain()[1] - xScale.domain()[0]) / (xScale.range()[1] - xScale.range()[0]));

const yStep = Math.abs((yScale.domain()[1] - yScale.domain()[0]) / (yScale.range()[1] - yScale.range()[0]));

yScale.range([yScale.range()[0], yScale.range()[0] - (yScale.domain()[1] - yScale.domain()[0]) / xStep]);

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - paddings[2]})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeInner(-height + paddings[2] + yScale.range()[1]));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${paddings[3]},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickValues(yScale.ticks().filter(function(d){return !(+d%10)})).tickSizeInner(-width + paddings[3] + paddings[1]));
```

```css
svg {
  border: 2px solid tan;
}

line {
  stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
  stroke: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As you can see using the gridlines, the units are equally spaced now.

Finally, have in mind that determining programmatically what scale will be changed, readjusting the correct range (your y scale, for instance, goes from the bottom to the top), centralising the axes etc are whole different issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It was exactly what I wanted. But I have one more question. How can I change the y axis black hard line to have all the tick positions. For example, In the example that you have shown, the y axis black hard line is only till 50 but I want that the black line to continue for all other points also.

Comment: @butterfly Sorry, it was just a typo in my snippet. Please check it again.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Hi and thank you for the answer. If I wanted to change the domain as well as the range?

Comment: @LucaMarangon please post this as a question, it's impossible to answer that in the comments section.